# OSM editing in JOSM

Tags: local, edit, openstreetmap

Finally i want to make my own local intranet map server with my changed tiles and nominatim. I just want to make an overview of security cameras in specific area of the map with geocoding (searching addresses).

In JOSM editor I downloaded the specific part of the map i want. Now i want to add new camera from presets to some place (no problem) with a symbol of a camera in the map (problem 1). Then what i want to do is to draw the area, which is monitored by this camera and fill this area with some color (problem 2). Then i want to save this map in osm format – load it to maperitive and generate tiles, which could look like my picture below. I tried to import to the map some picture with importimageplugin in JOSM, but after saving to osm format, loading to maperitive and rendering tiles, the picture wasn’t on the tiles (problem 3). Is possible to add icon of a camera and draw colored area of its monitoring in JOSM or in some other software?

I just read tutorials about nominatim install, but now the most important thing is to make the tiles with the security cameras and areas which are monitored by these cameras, because i am not shure, that i am able to install the nominatim, so i will be satisfied with a slippy map.

Sorry for my bad english and knowledge of osm, i am a beginner. I appreciate every answer.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywMFa.jpg) [Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsy3P.jpg)

Comment: In my opinion the best would be an external database and to render this information on top of existing OSM tiles. You can use Leaflet or OpenLayers for drawing your own icons and polygons on top of these tiles, just like in your pictures.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my next question is, how can i render png tiles of my modified map with Leaflet or Openlayers plugin. Maybe i found another possibility - Tilemill or Mapbox studio. I read about these programs and i should be able to import my own pictures to the map and then render mbtiles file. On the other hand i read, that is problematic to load an osm map to Tilemill or Mapbox studio. What do you think about it?

Comment: That's a different question I can't answer because I've never worked with TileMill or Mapbox Studio. But I can't think of any difficulty loading osm files because that's what these tools are made for.

Comment: I will try it with TileMill and Mapbox studio. Do you have any experience with rendering png tiles of modified map with Leaflet or Openlayers plugin?

Comment: Leaflet or Openlayers are mainly tools for displaying information on top of existing tiles with the help of JavaScript. They can't produce png tiles as far as I know. But usually this isn't necessary since the resulting map can be viewed with a regular browser.

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/47104/local-osm-editing

Comment: Sorry for the crosspost, but they helped me with this on help.openstreetmap.org.

Comment: Just mention it the next time so that people don't waste their time answering a question already answered elsewhere. Likewise other people might also be interested in the solution to your problem.